# Get reasonable long subsequences in multiple files

Tags: search, full-text-search, lcs

I have 3 files, each about 6MB in size, and I need to know what would be the blocks common in those files. With blocks I mean chunks of binary data 128 bytes long. Unfortunately, they might start anywhere. I need to know, where in the files those blocks occur. I've read some text about the *Longest Common Sequence Problem* but my problem is a bit different as I dont need the longest in 2 files but all reasonable long in 3 files. The blocks have no alignment, so a block of 128 bytes might start anywhere. Im pretty sure that this is quite *complex* but perhaps someone knows a smart solution for the problem, preferably with already existing tools.

I have a vague idea of how to code the most stupid version (compare everything with everything with everything) but I need a result in this century ;)